# How to fix code repetition and printing only the first line of file?

Tags: python, dictionary, repeat

I am trying to read the file as dictionary and want to print out the outcomes that check whether the input(name) is in the file or not. When I enter a name, it only prints the else statement although the name is in the file and prints the answer hundreds of times. How can I not repeat the same answer over and over? Can you please check my code?

```
d = {}
count = 0

for i in open("girlnames.txt", "r"):
  (nameG, numberG) = i.split()
  d[nameG] = numberG

count += 1  
print(name, d[name])  
if name in i:
  print("{} is ranked {} in popularity among {} girl names.".format(name, count, d[name]))
else: 
  print("{} is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.".format(name))
```

Comment: Please don't include pictures of code.  Cut and paste the code into your question, so we can try it.  BTW, you have `if name in i:` where you clearly wanted `if name in d:`.  And that's why you should use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Thank you! but this time the count += 1 doesn't work. I am supposed to print the value which tells the rank of the name in the file listed from most popular to least.

Comment: If the file is in order, then just use `enumerate(open(...))` to get both the ordinal and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is in rank order:

```
d = {}

for i,line in enumerate(open("girlnames.txt", "r")):
  nameG, numberG = line.split()
  d[nameG] = (i+1, numberG)

print(name, d[name])  
if name in d:
  print("{} is ranked {} in popularity with {}  names.".format(name, d[name][0], d[name][1])
else: 
  print("{} is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.".format(name))
```